# Cannot get width subtyping to work with exact types

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I created a type by "spreading" 2 exact types:

```
type Type1 = {|foo: number|};
type Type2 = {|bar: string|};
type Both = {|...Type1, ...Type2|};
```

And I don't understand why I can't get width subtyping to work as follow:

```
var a: Both = {foo: 42, bar: 'baz'};

function fooTest(arg: Type1) {
    console.log(arg.foo);
}

fooTest(a);
```

I get this error:

```
../\-:11: fooTest(a);
                  ^ Cannot call `fooTest` with `a` bound to `arg` because property `bar` is missing in `Type1` [1] but exists in `Both` [2]. [prop-missing]
References:
../\-:7: function fooTest(arg: Type1) {
                               ^ [1]
../\-:5: var a: Both = {foo: 42, bar: 'baz'};
                ^ [2]
```

But from [this page](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/intersections/), I gathered that I was allowed to pass extra properties but it seems that exact types prevent this behavior.

What's the proper way to do it, here?

[Try it](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAKuEEYoF4oG8A+AzA9jgXFAHYCuAtgEYQBOGAvgNwBQoks8ATCuhhQIbVCAZ2DUAlkQDm9Zq2gAhHMAAW3TADpNcSAgA0UTeu0QOMpkwBuAqH0KKVa3ASgAWDvv6CoAcn4Avb0ZzLBIiAGNgMRwiKCcYCBEACgFJQmMEAEp0JihcqDDooRwAGwh1YpxJZOpJdScM5jpgvHikvgamIA)

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @Aleksey L.'s pointers, I ended up turning the type of my function's argument to an inexact one:

```
function fooTest(arg: {...Type1}) {
    console.log(arg.foo);
}
```

Comment: Well exact means exact  It is not valid to pass an object with “extra” properties to an exact object type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not valid to pass an object with “extra” properties to an exact object type

> Exact object types disable width subtyping, and do not allow additional properties to exist.

More info [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/width-subtyping/)

Comment: Thanks, I understand why it's not working. I'm asking for the proper way to handle my issue.

Comment: Don't use exact types  Docs explicitly state that it wouldn't work with exact types

Comment: The Flow team also explains that whenever it's possible, exact type should be the rule. And exact type will become the default at some point. So, I'd rather keep using exact type and find a correct way to pass only a subset of my object.
Are you sure there's no way I could make this work, here ?

Comment: Well, this works but I wouldn't qualify it as elegant:
`function fooTest(arg: {...Type1}) {
    console.log(arg.foo);
}`

Comment: It is perfectly valid to use non exact types in scenarios where you don't care about "exactness". And `{...Type1}` is just turning it to non exact..

Comment: OK, I'll do that, then.
Thanks!